# How to get the child div number relative to the parent

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".child").click(function() {
    //var pos = how to get the position # from relative to the .parent?
});
```

For example: If I click on the div containing `4`, it should return `3`. If I click on the div showing `1`, it should return `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `index()` method:

```
$(".child").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).index();
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aw3r6fwL/)

Note that you could also provide a selector to `index()` to specify the set to find the index within, but as all the `.child` elements have the same container in this case it's not required.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just FYI, `position()` is used to retrieve the actual location on the screen of the element, relative to it's parent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.index(selector)` at this context,

```
$(".child").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).index(".parent > .child")
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/waj3jrv8/)

Or if your element arrangement is as simple as your sample html then you can simply use,

```
$(".child").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).index();
});
```

`index()` without a selector will give you the index of the current element based on its siblings.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for the answer.

Comment: +1 for the information that index() without a selector will give you the index of the current element based on its siblings.